# Unlock Sheets via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-365

I have an excel with a lot of formulas running and it goes to an executive team. Naturally I have locked the two summary pages to prevent formulas from being deleted accidentally but on some systems the file is just slow. I have added a VBA to convert all formulas into values (Pasted below) however it hits a wall on the locked sheets.

How can I have a single Macro that would unlock both Sheets 1 and 2 and convert all into values? (Sheet1 is named "Summary", Sheet2 is named "Details")

```
Sub AllValues()
Dim wSh As Worksheet
    For Each wSh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
         With wSh.UsedRange
             .Copy
             .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
          End With
    Next wSh
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are they locked via Password protection?  If not, just try `wsh.Unprotect`.  Also, it may be quicker instead of copy/pasting, to just do `wsh.UsedRange.Value = wsh.UsedRange.Value` (essentially, just set the values equal to eachother).

Comment: It's not locked via a passcode just locked to preview accidental deletion because I already got the "Why is there just a + there did you screw something up" comment.